# Cannot able to call the contract inside the truffle console

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am new to the `truffle` framework. I have initialised my contract  `Dapp` with the constructor function as given below

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Dapp {
    uint public totalSupply;

    constructor() public {
        totalSupply = 1000000;
    }
}
```

and my migrations file in regards with the contract is

```
const Dapp = artifacts.require("Dapp");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Dapp);
};
```

I have compiled and migrated using the command `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate`, which results in successful compilation.

But when accessing the contract in `truffle console` like

`let instance = await Dapp.deployed()`

It results in `ReferenceError: Dapp is not defined`, I cannot able to figure out what went wrong. Is there any possible solution to this. And yeah I have followed the latest `Truffle documentation`. And also, I have followed the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045814/cant-call-contract-function-in-truffle-console) been presented in this platform.

Documentation link for [migration](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations) and [interacting with truffle console](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts).

Comment: Are you sure that you running truffle console from your project directory?

Comment: @VitalyMigunov, yes i am sure